# Multithreading doing something while on wait

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I've a program that basically has a matrix of cells(shared memory) and cars(observable threads). Before each movement each car asks for access to the next cell, and if the next is blocked it enters a synchronized block which calls wait(), and the thread goes to sleep. I was wondering if there was any way I could make the car do something while it's on wait(), and then when he gets notified he can keep on doing what he was doing before the wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to redesign: don't model cars with threads. Have a thread pool perform any needed tasks and have an asynchronous model with callback functions guide the behavior of cars. If a cell is blocked, the state of the car simply doesn't change and the thread pool can do something else. When the cell is freed, fire the appropriate callback, which will submit the update task to the pool.

Comment: i've looked into that but I don't think I'll be able to use thread pool instead of thread in the car class, mainly because all cars aren't instantiated at the same time. I have several garages with list's inside them that is where all the cars are "parked", this means that I do new Thread(car).start() from each garage, and for example each garage starts 2 new cars that have as a destination another garage..

Comment: My proposal runs quite a bit deeper than just replacing a thread with a thread pool. Your design, which tightly binds a modelled entity (a car) to a thread, is fundamentally flawed and no production-worthy system would dare to be designed like that. In fact, you probably don't need multithreading at all---you need something like Swing, one thread that runs the main event-dispatching loop, and all the code in event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to what you describe, using `Handler`s for 2-way thread communication.

- child/worker/'car' thread does work, goes to sleep for a set period (~100ms), and when waking up checks a thread class member variable for state changes.
- parent thread will send `Handler` messages to the worker thread, and the worker thread receives the commands and sets member variable in worker thread class, to be detected next time the worker exits sleep.

Below are the links I've been reviewing to grasp how to use `Handler`s and communicate between threads effectively:

- threads - nice overview of handlers (withOUT looper). w/ code example: `com.indy.testing.TestMain.java.MyThread.java`
  http://indyvision.net/2010/02/android-threads-tutorial-part-3/
- threads - ok overview of handlers and loopers
  http://techtej.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html
- threads w/ 2way comm. w/ code example: sample.thread.messaging.ThreadMessaging.java
  http://codinghard.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/android-thread-messaging/